# Find type of the content (number, date, time, string etc.) inside a string

Tags: ruby, string, parsing, types

I'm trying to parse a CSV file and automatically create a table for it using SQL commands. The first line in the CSV gives the column headers. But I need to infer the column type for each one.

Is there any function in Ruby that would find the type of the content in each field. 
For example, the CSV line:

```
"12012", "Test", "1233.22", "12:21:22", "10/10/2009"
```

should produce the types like

```
['integer', 'string', 'float', 'time', 'date']
```

Thanks!

Comment: From the looks of it you might be contemplating using floats for money... warning, there be dragons

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
require 'time'

def to_something(str)
  if (num = Integer(str) rescue Float(str) rescue nil)
    num
  elsif (tm = Time.parse(str)) == Time.now
    # Time.parse does not raise an error for invalid input
    str
  else 
    tm
  end
end

%w{12012 1233.22 12:21:22 10/10/2009 Test}.each do |str|
  something = to_something(str)
  p [str, something, something.class]
end
```

Results in

```
["12012", 12012, Fixnum]
["1233.22", 1233.22, Float]
["12:21:22", Sat Sep 12 12:21:22 -0400 2009, Time]
["10/10/2009", Sat Oct 10 00:00:00 -0400 2009, Time]
["Test", "Test", String]
```

---

Update for ruby 1.9.3: the Time class in the stdlib now does throw an exception if it can't parse the string, so:

```
def to_something(str)
  duck = (Integer(str) rescue Float(str) rescue Time.parse(str) rescue nil)
  duck.nil? ? str : duck
end
```

Comment: If you want to save the variable, `Integer(str) rescue Float(str) rescue Time.parse(str) rescue nil || str` works.

Comment: I make one slight modification to this. If a non-string is passed in, there is no need to parse it as it is already (assuming) in the correct class. My use case wanted to determine the class, so if you want the value the logic needs to change. `if str.class != String
        str.class
    else
        duck = (... `

Comment: Sadly, `Time#parse` will result in false positives with things words that contain substrings that might be interpreted as abbreviations for month names, weekdays, etc. E.g: `Time.parse("Marketing") => 2018-03-01 00:00:00 +0100`. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

### This might get you started

I don't have a complete solution, but this may help get you started. You can go from an example record to an array of Class objects to a string representation automatically, at least for some types, and then translate the strings...

```
$ irb
>> t = { "String" => "string", "Fixnum" => "integer", "Float" => "float" }
=> {"Float"=>"float", "Fixnum"=>"integer", "String"=>"string"}
>> ["xyz", 123, 123.455].map { |x| t[x.class.to_s] }
=> ["string", "integer", "float"]
```

You could map the classes directly, actually:

```
$ irb
>> t = { String => "string", Fixnum => "integer", Float => "float" }
=> {String=>"string", Float=>"float", Fixnum=>"integer"}
>> ["xyz", 123, 123.455].map { |x| t[x.class] }
=> ["string", "integer", "float"]
```

Comment: Hi digitalross. Thanks for the suggestion. But I would need to know whether the string "123" is a number or not. In the example you provided it was the type-name of the number 123 that got mapped.

ie, would it be possible to get
["xyz","123","123.455"] mapped into ["string", "integer", "float"] ?

Comment: In your question you didn't have quotes around the integers and the floats, only the strings and dates. If in fact everything is quoted you really should edit your question's example to reflect that. :-) I was designing to the wrong test case! :-) Perhaps you could show a piece of the real input?

Comment: OOPS! It was a bad oversight. I'm sorry.. the question has been corrected. And Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're parsing a CSV take a look at this awesome solution from [Parsing CSV with Ruby](http://technicalpickles.com/posts/parsing-csv-with-ruby/)

```
require 'csv'

CSV::Converters[:blank_to_nil] = lambda do |field|
  field && field.empty? ? nil : field
end

body = "col1,col2\nq,r\n1,2"
csv = CSV.new(body, :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol, :converters => [:all, :blank_to_nil])
csv_hash = csv.to_a.map {|row| row.to_hash }

csv_hash.each do |row|
  puts row
  puts row.map{ |k,v|  v.class }.join(",")
end
```

**Output**

```
{:col1=>"q", :col2=>"r"}
String,String
{:col1=>1, :col2=>2}
Fixnum,Fixnum
```